# Бесконечный ListView

Tags: java, listview, retrofit

Добрый день. Скажите пожалуйста как можно организовать список который при нажатии по элементу списка формировал такой же список только с другими значениями и так пока не закончатся значения)). Я хотел бы увидеть как это реализовано с retrofit 2. Но и просто наводку не отказался бы увидеть. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте код, который уже пытались делать и опишите причину, что не получилось.

Comment: Я не могу найти пример где бы так было реализовано

Comment: Я хочу получить структуру примерно как в файловом менеджере.

Comment: Через какой-нибудь `TreeMap`.

Comment: хотя бы в paint картинку нарисуй; какие значения должны появляться?